# Autocomplete in WxPython Phoenix STC

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, scintilla, wxpython

I am creating a WxPython App which has an STC widget. Basically, it is a code editor which has syntax highlight. But as you know autocomplete is a very important feature in code editors I want to also have it in my editor. The docs list many methods for Autocompletion but don't have any snippet or tutorial.

Please help and thanks in advance!